# Is there a way to distinguish resource requestor via PHP or .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

Is there a way to distinguish between a browser loading a web page that requests a resource (e.g., `<script src="https://www.example.com/requested_script.js"></script>` vs. a resource being requested directly (no referer) by typing its URL directly into the URL bar, by using either PHP or .htaccess?

I'm trying to secure a JavaScript file from being R & D'ed (Ripped-Off and Duplicated) by directing the server to serve a bogus (i.e., fake) JavaScript file if the would-be thief tries to view the file contents/source-code directly, while at the same time, serving the real JavaScript file to the browser as a legitimate resource.

Comment: You might be looking for [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If you can share, you can also not share. But in the end there's nothing to stop people from loading a JS file in a browser, if they want to.

Comment: The browser will download the JS, no matter what you might try. Unpacking packed JS is also no problem. And CORS only affects the content-embedding in a web-browser, nothing else. Putting client-side JS and security in the same sentence is quite a stretch. Just press `F12` and then `F5` to see how pointless this is.

Comment: One of my creative ideas was to use a php file as the js resource, containing a conditional if statement that would serve `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');` and afterward either `echo` the actual JavaScript content or bogus content, depending on the referer. 

Comment: Though **this technique could be very very dangerous in the wrong hands**, here is a proof of concept:

Source Code: https://www.jamesandersonjr.com/pub-pocs/php/resource-thief.php?view-source=true

Result: https://www.jamesandersonjr.com/pub-pocs/php/resource-thief.php

Comment: Please +1 if you like the above technique. It helps. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a hash as the end of the redirects, one only being the genuine one.

Something like

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/requested_script.js?frX543FVd34fgf"></script>
```

To make it more difficult to read use an obfusctator, for example:

**https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home**

It will also reduce the size of the file.

But if your main concern is that you're running "proprietary" operations in the Javascript you better move those to the server side, then just send to the client the final calculations/values, this way no one sees how you obtain them.

Any other info unfortunately will be ALWAYS visible to the client, because that's the way the browser reads it.